# WhereIn in eloquent orm

Tags: php, laravel, orm, eloquent

I have two arrays

```
temp[]
time[]
```

now for example if i have data in my array something like this

```
    temp   time 
[0]  80     45
[1]  70     50
[2]  85     65
[3]  90     30
```

i want to query data in terms of these two array params 
like (select * from MyTable where (temperature = 80 and time = 45 ))for the next  (select * from MyTable where (temperature = 70 and time = 50 )) and so on

I am doing something like this

```
 $mix=MyTable::whereIN('temperature', $temp)
         ->whereIN('time', $time)->where('category',$cat)
         ->get();
```

But the output it is qiving me is kind of a combination of these two params.not exactly from array 0 to onwards...

I hope i explained my question correctly..

i tried this..

```
    $result=Ergebnisse::where('name_id', $nam)->where('geometrie_id', $geo)->get();
    foreach ($result as $key => $res) {

$mix=Ergebnisse::where('temperatur', $res->temperatur)
         ->where('zeit', $res->zeit)->groupBy('katogorie_id')
         ->get();

}
```

when i dd($mix) it shows only one result. but according to my db it should show more than one

Comment: Could you try a foreach loop? Use a foreach loop to go through the two arrays and then make the query using the values: $mix=MyTable::where('temperature', $temp)->where('time', $time)->where('category',$cat)->first();

Comment: it doesnt work showing only one result

Comment: One result? Could you update the question to also include the new code you tried?

Comment: $mix[] = Ergebnisse::where('temperatur', $res->temperatur)
         ->where('zeit', $res->zeit)->groupBy('katogorie_id')
         ->get();

Comment: $mix = Ergebnisse::where('katogorie_id', $kat)
    ->where(function($q) use($result) {               
        foreach ($result as $item) {
             $q->orWhere(function($q) use($item) {
                 $q->where('temperatur', $item->temperatur)
                   ->where('zeit', $item->zeit);
            });
        }
    })->groupBy('name_id')->get();    I got it solved by the help of @Alexey Mezenin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`whereIn()` will not work here. Do something like this:

```
$data = MyTable::where('category', $cat)
    ->where(function($q) use($array) {               
        foreach ($array as $item) {
             $q->orWhere(function($q) use($item) {
                 $q->where('temperature', $item['temp'])
                   ->where('time', $item['time']);
            }
        }
    })->get();
```

Comment: @HassanHaroon `$array` is an array with data. Just use variable name you use in your app.

Comment: i am  new to laravel and orm .i did that now it saysUndefined variable: data

Comment: $result=Ergebnisse::where('name_id', $nam)->where('geometrie_id', $geo)->get();

Comment: $data = Ergebnisse::where('katogorie_id', $kat)
    ->where(function($q) use($result) {               
        foreach ($result as $item) {
            $data = $data->orWhere(function($q) use($item) {
                $q->where('temperature', $item['temp'])
                  ->where('time', $item['time']);
            });
        }
    })->get();